# Inapp purchase in iphone

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I am new in iphone and i am on the final stage of my first project for iPhone.I need some help in Inapp purchase implementation.I need to give a free version of my app for thirty days and then force the user to buy the app.Please let me know how can i start implement this.Looking forward for valuable advices.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't release a time limited app of any kind through the Apple Store.

The iPhone business model does not work like that for non-moblies. Apple will not let you release a time limited application of any kind.

Instead, you have to create a "lite" version that has some but not all the full application's features and release that for free. The lite version can have a link to upgrade to the full version but it must be a functioning app in its own right.

So, you need to start over from scratch thinking about your app. You need to develop two versions.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to manage the activation over the network - if you try storing the "shareware" date locally, then you'll create a state where users can just wipe the app and re-install every 29th day. But then if the user always runs your application in airplane mode, they'll never contact the activation server, so you'll need to manage activation locally :-).